# Aggregated Dataset in Lookup

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have 3 datasets.

- Dataset 1 - Main Dataset used in Tablix 1
- Dataset 2 - We have different query with 4 columns
- Dataset 3 - Same query as Dataset 2 but group by is different. it has only 3 columns. basically the subset of Dataset 2.

We have to use combined Dataset1 with 2 & 3 using lookup. is there any option to ignore Dataset 3 and get the another aggregation layer on top of Dataset 2 and do a lookup?

More Details
This is using Teradata as a source. We have achieved the solution - Displaying the result in a single tablix using lookup. Lookup Dataset 1 & Dataset 2 and again Dataset 1 with Dataset 3.

The query used in the Dataset 3 is same as Dataset 2 but only the group by is different. Dataset 3 has Month and Category as a columns but Dataset 2 has Month, Category and SubCategory as a columns. I am looking for optimization (reducing one query run) like reusing the Dataset 2 wherever we have Dataset3 is used but aggregated data in Dataset 2 is different than Dataset 3.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also tag with the database you are using, which is presumably SQL Server.

Comment: Is this even related to the <sql> _language_?

Comment: Added some more information on the same question